# Правка csv средствами вэб странички

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток. В инете нашел как читать csv, как править инфы не найду :-(

Как в файле csv удалить строчку? Вот, к примеру, файл test.csv, прыгнуть на строку с номером $x, грохнуть ее. Аналогично, как стереть все, что в строке, и записать туда $y? Ну и бонусный вопрос, как прыгнуть на строку $x, сделать отступ, и в эту строку добавить $y?

Охота без дополнительных библиотек, без дополнительных файлов jquery, желательно без JS, в идеале на PHP )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эх, ну раз никто не отвечает...
Я бы скачал этот файл в переменную-массив и удалял бы строки из массива. Потом записывал бы в файл.
Если файл слишком большой - выгрузка в БД с последующей обработкой ТАМ.

Comment: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php][1]

[1]:http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php